# Instalar SSL en Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

hola amigos quiero instalar mi ssl en el cpanel de un dominio que adquirir pero me da este errror

```
Template::Exception:
    [TYPE]=[undef]
    [INFO]=[SSL::installed_hosts(HASH(0x23d5540)) failed: No tiene la función “sslinstall”.
]
    [TEXT]=[]
 at cpanel.pl line 1121.
    cpanel::cpanel::cptt_exectag("/usr/local/cpanel/base/frontend/paper_lantern/ssl/install.htm"..., 1) called at cpanel.pl line 4489
    cpanel::cpanel::run_standard_mode() called at cpanel.pl line 925
    cpanel::cpanel::script("cpanel::cpanel", "./frontend/paper_lantern/ssl/install.html.tt") called at cpanel.pl line 323
```

Ademas de que como tal no viene un opcion de instalar y administrar ssl entre las opciones ssl del panel, alguien sabe a que se deba?

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes acceso a WHMC puesdes habilitarlo en:

“WHM >> Packages >> Feature Manager”.

De lo contrario, la única opción aquí sería que su proveedor NO permita esta función y que ellos instalen el certificado por usted.